# Where Audacious store recorded live audio stream?

Tags: streaming, audio-recording, audacious

Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS, Audacious 3.6.2
Where Audacious store recorded live audio stream?

Comment: `cd audacious`
`bash: cd: audacious: No such file or directory`

Comment: Check some hidden folders like `~/.audacious` or `~/.cache/audacious`.

Comment: Didn't you tell it where to write to in the settings?

Comment: I used default FileWriter Plugin settings, which use Home folder.
'Save into original directory', 'Output file folder': username. But didn't find recorded file there.

Comment: "Save into original directory" and "Output file folder" are mutually exclusive. You should uncheck "Save into original directory" when recording a live stream.

Comment: But where is this "original directory" located, anyway? Didn't find any explanation.